# Screen-scrape paginated data

Tags: javascript, ajax, screen-scraping

I'm trying to grab a list of all of the available stores returned from the search at this website.

https://www.metropcs.com/find-store.html.html

The issue is that it returns back only 4 or 5 at a time, and does not have the option for 'See All'. I attempted to use Post Man in Chrome and AutoPager in Firefox to see if I could somehow see all of the data in the background but I wasn't able to. I also was researching JSON interception tools, as I believe the site is using JSON in the return set, but I wasn't able to find any of the actual data that I needed.

In the past I was able to hit 'print preview' and grab the list that way (then I just copy-pasted to Excel and ran some custom macros to strip the data I need) but the printer-friendly version is gone now as well.

Any ideas on tools that would allow me to export all of the stores found, especially for larger return sets?

Answer (score 0):

You want to manipulate this request:
`https://www.metropcs.com/apps/mpcs/servlet/genericservlet`

You'll notice the page sends this (among other things) as the request to that URL:

```
inputReqParam=
  {"serviceProviderName":"Hbase","expectedParams":
     {"Corporate Stores":...Truncated for clarity...},
   "requestParams":
     {"do":"json",
      "minLatitude":"39.89234063913044",
      "minLongitude":"-74.85258152641507",
      "maxLongitude":"-74.96578907358492",
      "maxLatitude":"39.979297160869564"
     },
   "serviceName":"metroPCSStoreLocator"}
```

You'll need to manipulate the lat and long bounding box to encompass the area you want. (The entire US is something like [-124.848974, 24.396308] to [-66.885444, 49.384358] )

In your favorite browser it should be easy enough to tweak the request to get a JSON response with what you require.